# Comparing Ints concatenated from Strings in Python

Tags: python, string, int, comparison, concatenation

So I am trying to write a program using Python that will send a text reminder after a certain amount of time. I am trying to check if the time is within a realistic range (i.e. no more or less than 24 hours in a day) but i'm getting an error when trying to compare them. I am unable to compare ints that were concatenated from a string.

```py
dur = input("How long do you want to wait (EX: HHMMSS): ")
hours = int(dur[0:1])
minutes = int(dur[2:3])
seconds = int(dur[4:5])
print(hours)
print(minutes)
print(seconds)

for n in range(0, LOOP):
    if(count == 0):
        # Check if hours is realistic
        if(hours > 0 and hours < 24 and str(hours[0]) == 0):
            hours = hours[1]
            count += 1
```

I am getting an TypeError saying > not supported between instances of str and int. Since I can't compare them with > or <, how can I do it?

Comment: By the way, to get the first two characters, you need `[0:2]` or simply `[:2]`. The correct ranges are `[0:2]`, `[2:4]`, and `[4:6]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```py
hours = int(dur[0:2])
minutes = int(dur[2:4])
seconds = int(dur[4:6])

for n in range(0, LOOP):
    if(count == 0):
        # Check if hours is realistic
        if(hours > 0 and hours < 24 and hours < 10):
            ...
```

And another thing that you cannot use `hours = hours[1]` 
because `'int' object is not subscriptable`.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing dates and times is not worth doing by hand. Your code attempts to index into an integer with `hours[0]`. Strings and integer types aren't comparable without a cast.

Try Python's [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module, specifically the `strptime` function, which parses a date from a formatted string. You can extract hours, minutes, seconds and easily perform comparisons and add/subtract time using `timedelta`.

```
from datetime import datetime

while 1:
    try:
        dur = input("How long do you want to wait (EX: HHMMSS): ")
        dt = datetime.strptime(dur, "%H%M%S")
        print(dt, " hour:", dt.hour, " min:", dt.minute, " sec:", dt.second)        
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid time.")
```

Sample run:

```
How long do you want to wait (EX: HHMMSS): 012261
Invalid time.
How long do you want to wait (EX: HHMMSS): 012251
1900-01-01 01:22:51  hour: 1  min: 22  sec: 51
```